# Jetpack Compose can't observe MutableLiveData

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, retrofit, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

View

```kotlin
    viewModel.todoLists.observe(lifecycleOwner){
        it?.let {  label.value = it.toString() }

    }
```

ViewModel

```kotlin
val todoLists : MutableLiveData <ListResponse>  = MutableLiveData()

 fun getTodoList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = api.getTodos("Bearer ${jwt.value.toString()}")

                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    val list = response.body()!!
                    todoLists.value = list // it works
                } 

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.message?.let {
                    Log.d("Login TLVM", it)
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

I can fetch data in ViewModel, but I cannot get data from the LiveData in the View. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use provided [`observeAsState()`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/df451e0084ea72182f980c95e8ed42e2516110f1:compose/runtime/runtime-livedata/src/main/java/androidx/compose/runtime/livedata/LiveDataAdapter.kt;l=41) extension function to observe `LiveData` from compose. It will look like this:

```
val list = viewModel.todoLists.observeAsState()
```

Now `list` always has the most recent value of `viewModel.todoLists`. When you set new value inside of your `ViewModel`, your composable will recompose to use that new value.

If you would want to add observer to your `LiveData` instead, you have to do so inside of `LaunchedEffect`:

```
LaunchedEffect(viewModel) {
    viewModel.todoLists.observe(lifecycleOwner){
        it?.let {  label.value = it.toString() }
    }
}
```

Comment: I wonder if there might be an error in my lifecycle because it didn't work
val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

Comment: That looks alright. Did you try the first option as well? Is that working? You should add the `lifecycleOwner` to LaucnhedEffect keys as well, but I'm not sure if that helps: `LaunchedEffect(viewModel, lifecycleOwner) {...}`

Comment: didn't work again, val lists = viewModel.todoLists.observeAsState() returns null

Comment: it takes todoLists.value = list value in viewmodel but I can't display it in view it's weird

Comment: well that's weird, are you sure you have the same instance of your viewmodel? How do you create it?

Comment: I think there is an error in the viewmodel because I can't even use the authtoken in the other function, it returns null
my viewmodel : 
https://gist.github.com/yusuftalhaklc/7b6c4a60d0d514b7250548256a465f6a

Comment: `if (response.isSuccessful) {  ... } else { todoLists.value = mock a simple valid response // put this line inside else and try }`

Comment: there is no need for it because it doesn't go inside the else block, I check it with  Log.d("Login List Failure", response.message())anyway

Comment: again, how do you **instantiate** that viewmodel?

Comment: like this https://gist.github.com/yusuftalhaklc/e5af27ea19c20d6a91f1f30ffc73039a

Comment: no thats not instantiation. Where you get the `viewModel` variable from?? Do you call `val viewModel = LoginViewModel()`? Is it from some library? Compose navigation, hilt?

Comment: like this `@Composable
fun TodoScreen(navController : NavController ,context: Context, viewModel: LoginViewModel = LoginViewModel(context))`

here my projects [Link](https://github.com/yusuftalhaklc/jcompose-todoapp-fastapi)

Comment: yeah, thats exactly the problem, you are creating new instance of viewmodel every time the composable recomposes, you cannot do that.